# Flatten out a JSON hash map to an array in perl

Tags: arrays, json, perl, hash, hashmap

I am new to data structures and I have a question about it,

I have a JSON file

```
    {
    "COMP1":[
        {
            "machines"      :   "xyz",
            "logLocation"   :   "a.log",
            "duration"      :   "1h",
            "network"       :   "prefix1",
            "searchString"  :   [
                "ERR",
                "CRIT",
                "WARN"

            ],
            "ignoreSearch"  :   [
                "DEFERRED",
                "ABCCRITXYZ"
            ]
        },
        {
            "machines"      :   "sql2",
            "logLocation"   :   "a.log",
            "duration"      :   "1d",
            "network"       :   "imcr",
            "searchString"  :   [
                "ERR",
                "CRIT",
                "WARN"

            ],
            "ignoreSearch"  :   [
                "DEFERRED",
                "ABCCRITXYZ"
            ]
        }
   ],
    "COMP2":[
        {
            "machines"      :   "sql",
            "logLocation"   :   "a.log",
            "duration"      :   "1h",
            "network"       :   "prefix-1",
            "searchString"  :   [
                "ERR",
                "CRIT",
                "WARN"

            ],
            "ignoreSearch"  :   [
                "DEFERRED",
                "ABCCRITXYZ"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to flatten out this into arrays on the basis of the array of "searchString"

```
[
   {


 "comp"          : "comp1",
 "machines"      :   "xyz",
 "logLocation"   :   "a.log",
 "duration"      :   "1h",
 "network"       :   "prefix1",
 "searchString"  :    "ERR",
 "ignoreSearch"  : ["DEFERRED","ABCCRITXYZ"]
    },

  {
    "comp"          : "comp1",
    "machines"      :   "xyz",
    "logLocation"   :   "a.log",
    "duration"      :   "1h",
    "network"       :   "prefix1",
    "searchString"  :   "CRIT",
     "ignoreSearch"  : ["DEFERRED","ABCCRITXYZ"]
    },

   {
    "comp"          : "comp1",
    "machines"      :   "xyz",
    "logLocation"   :   "a.log",
    "duration"      :   "1h",
    "network"       :   "prefix1",
    "searchString"  :   "WARN",
     "ignoreSearch"  : ["DEFERRED","ABCCRITXYZ"]
    }
],

[
   {
    "comp"          : "comp1",
 "machines"      :   "sql2",
 "logLocation"   :   "a.log",
 "duration"      :   "1h",
 "network"       :   "imcr",
 "searchString"  :    "ERR",
 "ignoreSearch"  : ["DEFERRED","ABCCRITXYZ"]
    },

  {
    "comp"          : "comp1",
    "machines"      :   "sql2",
    "logLocation"   :   "a.log",
    "duration"      :   "1h",
    "network"       :   "imcr",
    "searchString"  :   "CRIT",
     "ignoreSearch"  : ["DEFERRED","ABCCRITXYZ"]
    },

   {
    "comp"          : "comp1",
    "machines"      :   "xyz",
    "logLocation"   :   "a.log",
    "duration"      :   "1h",
    "network"       :   "prefix1",
    "searchString"  :   "WARN",
     "ignoreSearch"  : ["DEFERRED","ABCCRITXYZ"]
    }
]
```

and so on,
How to store them so that I can access them individually later? 
The same will be for comp2.
Sorry about my indentation, I do not ask here that much.

Comment: Re: "_I do not ask here that much_" -- but here you are asking for much.  It appears that you are simply asking for someone to do the thing for you.  Can you show what you've done and where you are stuck so that someone can help you out?

Comment: @zdim by that comment, I have not asked many questions and it related to the fact that my indentation can be improper.
I am stuck on this and looking for a headstart on this

Comment: You need to do research. This is a site to ask specific programming questions about code that you've already written, and are having a specific problem with. It's not a code-writing service, nor is it a place where we recommend external resources. Please read through [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: @hitman99  Yes, I understood that.  My comment played with that wording -- to let you know that you appear to be asking for code to solve your problem.  (Somehow I don't think that you actually had that in mind.)  As for the "headstart" -- my second comment really answers your question.  What data structure to use, a package that gives you that, and information that there is a lot of that on SO.  I hope that that gives you the headstart.  Let us know how to coding goes.

Comment: _This is "my second comment" referred to above, rewritten._   Rules to convert JSON to Perl data are simple. Associations `X : Y` call for hashes.  Lists `a, b, c` fit in arrays. And hash/array _references_ are scalars that can be elements of an array or value for a key in a hash.  You get such a complex data structure when you read that JSON file into a program using [JSON](http://search.cpan.org/~ishigaki/JSON-2.94/lib/JSON.pm), or better [JSON_XS](http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/JSON-XS-3.02/XS.pm). Then build that structure you show from it. Also, search SO for perl+JSON. There's _a lot_.

Comment: thanks @zdim, going through that now

Comment: LIterature: tutorial [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html), data structures cookbook [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html), reference [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html). SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use JSON qw( decode_json encode_json from_json to_json );

sub dclone { from_json(to_json($_[0])) }

my $foos_by_comp = decode_json(...);

my @flattened_foos_grouped_by_comp;
for my $comp (keys(%$foos_by_comp)) {
   my @flattened_foos_of_comp;
   my $foo = $foos_by_comp->{$comp};
   for my $search_string (@{ $foo->{searchString} }) {
       my $flattened_foo = dclone($foo);
       $flattened_foo->{ comp         } = $comp;
       $flattened_foo->{ searchString } = $search_string;
       push @flattened_foos_of_comp, $flattened_foo;
   }

   push @flattened_foos_grouped_by_comp, \@flattened_foos_of_comp;
}

print(encode_json(\@flattened_foos_grouped_by_comp));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done something like this. Your comments and suggestions are welcome. 
Also thank you @ikegami and @zdim for headstarts.

```
use JSON qw( decode_json encode_json from_json to_json );


my $component = decode_json($json);

sub dclone { from_json(to_json($_[0])) }


my @grouped_by_comp;
my @testData;
foreach my $comp (keys %$component){                                     # $comp is an array reference , keys %$component gives an array reference 
    foreach my $test_map (@{$component->{$comp}}){                       #@{$component->{$comp}} is a hash reference in array 
        my $searchStrings = $test_map->{searchString};                      #$test_map->{searchString} is an array reference within a hash 
        foreach my $search ( @$searchStrings ){
            my %tmp_map = %$test_map;
            $tmp_map{component} = $comp;
            $tmp_map{searchString} = $search;
            $tmp_map{ignoreSearch} = [@{$test_map->{ignoreSearch}}];
            push @testData,\%tmp_map;
        }
    }
}
print Dumper(\@testData);
```